# Generate current year using Docusign formula tag

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently working with Docusign and developing a form so that the current year and next year populates under the title like so:

2017-2018

These years would require two separate formulas,one to calculate the current year and one to calculate the following year. I don't want anything but the year to be generated.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the DocuSign Rest api to create the envelope?

Comment: Yes I am using the newer version of DocuSign

Answer (score 0):

The formula tab does not support displaying just the year.

See the list of formulas supported [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-calculated-fields).

Instead you can use a Text Tab and set the value "2015-2016".